# Classe bootstrap não funciona com htmlhelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Estou começando agora a trabalhar com MVC, Razor, Bootstrap etc., e estou tendo um problema de design.

Esses 2 `textarea` estão usando as mesmas classes, está tudo igualzinho, exceto que em um eu carrego valor da minha *model*, então tenho que usar html helper, e a de baixo é só html puro.

```html
        <div class="form-group">          
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Definicao, 5, 45, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })            
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">         
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="model.Definicao" rows="5" cols="45" ></textarea> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

Onde uso o *helper* a classe css não carrega no meu `form`, alguém sabe se isso é bug ou eu que tô fazendo algo errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Definicao, new { @class = "form-control",  rows="20", @cols="50" })
```